# Semantic proof of $\varphi \models (\forall x)\varphi$

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

How to semantically show this statment?

$$\varphi \models (\forall x)\varphi$$
I'm very new to first order logic and I don't even know if this statment holds or not. What does the symbol $\models$ mean in this case? I have read that quantifiers do not change truth value (if there are no free variables) but I am not sure what exactly this statment says.

Comment: The relation expresses the validity of the rule of [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization). See also the post: [restrictions on the use of Universal generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969231/restrictions-on-the-use-of-universal-generalization).

Comment: More detail is needed: is $\phi$ a sentence? if not, the theorem depends on the way that the $\vDash$ relation is defined. What is your definition of $\vDash$ for non-sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $\vDash$ means *entailment* or [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence).

The proof relies on the details of the *semantics* specifications.

According to one approach (see: Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA67), Springer (5th ed. 2013), page 67) we have that the definition of meaning and truth value is limited to *sentences*, i.e. "closed" formulas.

For open one, the following convention is adopted:

> $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi$  **iff** $\mathfrak A \vDash \text{Cl}(\varphi)$,

where $\text{Cl}(\varphi)$ is the *universal closure* of $\varphi$.

Having said that, we have that $\Gamma \vDash \psi \text { iff (if } \mathfrak A \vDash \Gamma \text {, then } \mathfrak A \vDash \psi)$, where $\Gamma$ and $\psi$ are *sentences*.

If so, the proof of $\varphi \vDash (\forall x) \varphi$ is trivial, because it amounts to:

> if $\mathfrak A \vDash \text {Cl}(\varphi)$, then $\mathfrak A \vDash(\forall x) \varphi$.

But if there are no free variables, then $\text {Cl}(\varphi)=\varphi$.